# Replace values ​in a column with similar values ​in another column with different size - Python

Tags: python, levenshtein-distance

I have a dataframe with different values ​​in a column (about 6,000 rows), which I need to replace with similar (but differents) values ​​found in another dataframe, which has fewer rows.

| Store | Values to replace |
| --- | --- |
| Store A 05/15/21 | Store A |
| The Store B 04/01/21 | Store B |
| Store letter B 11/12/21 | Store C |
| Store C 10/24/21 | Store D |
| Store D 09/30/21 |  |
| the Store C 05/13/21 |  |
| Store letter D 07/01/21 |  |
| Store letter A 08/29/21 |  |

The goal is for the final dataframe to look like this:

| Store |
| --- |
| Store A |
| Store B |
| Store B |
| Store C |
| Store D |
| Store C |
| Store D |
| Store A |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `df` and `df2`:

```
                     Store
0         Store A 05/15/21
1     The Store B 04/01/21
2  Store letter B 11/12/21
3         Store C 10/24/21
4         Store D 09/30/21
5     the Store C 05/13/21
6  Store letter D 07/01/21
7  Store letter A 08/29/21

  replace_values
0        Store A
1        Store B
2        Store C
3        Store D
```

Doing:

```
df.Store = df.Store.str.split()
df2.replace_values = df2.replace_values.str.split()
df.Store = df.Store.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(x for x in row if any(x in i for i in df2.replace_values)))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Store
0  Store A
1  Store B
2  Store B
3  Store C
4  Store D
5  Store C
6  Store D
7  Store A
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
list_values = []
for i in df['Store']:
    value = i[:-9]
    list_values.append(value)

df['Values_to_replace'] = list_values
```

The output:

```
    Store                    Values_to_replace
0   Store A 05/15/21         Store A
1   The Store B 04/01/21     The Store B
2   Store letter B 11/12/21  Store letter B
3   Store C 10/24/21         Store C
4   Store D 09/30/21         Store D
5   the Store C 05/13/21     the Store C
6   Store letter D 07/01/21  Store letter D
7   Store letter A 08/29/21  Store letter A
```

Comment: Thanks Luis, but in the real dataframe the stores have names of different sizes, so when applying the code the result cuts the name of some stores

Comment: Please provide an example of your real dataframe then.

Comment: Hello Luis. I edited the question with the mentioned example